# CSS / jQuery - 16x9 aspect ratio image - Match div dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, aspect-ratio

I have a simple layout where I am forcing an image to have an aspect ratio of 16x9 like this...

```css
.image1 {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.2%;
}

.image1 img {
 position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image2 {
  background:lightgreen;
}

.image3 {
  background:lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="image1">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/2012_Suedchinesischer_Tiger.JPG/1200px-2012_Suedchinesischer_Tiger.JPG" />
  </div>

  <div class="image2">
   Section 2
  </div>

  <div class="image3">
  Section 3
  </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to make the other 2 divs `.image2` and `.image3` have the same dimensions as the `.image1` div.

Is jQuery the way to go on this one of is there anything I can do with CSS to achieve it?

Comment: Why not put "padding-bottom: 56.2%;" to the other 2 divs also?

Answer (score 0):

Not really possible this way I think.

I would create an transparent image, with 16px width and 9px height. Put this in the content. And then your div will always be the correct size.

Then you can put an absolute image over it.